# SQL Server add index without dropping table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add an index to a table that already has the primary key indexed. The new index will be on another column.

I don't have enough permissions on this table to select 'Alter' by right clicking and selecting **'Script table as'**.

Is there any way to add an index to a column without effecting any of the existing data?

> **myTable**:
>
> - id -- int -----> this is an identity column, set as PK and indexable
> - bookid ---> varchar(20)  ----> this is the column that needs index created

Comment: try searching on the 'create index' command.

Comment: [`CREATE INDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) would be the proper command, and adding a non-clustered index never affects the data.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

Comment: Adding non-clustered index doesn't affect the data. You are using some external tool btw which you forgot to mention.

Comment: I'm interested what platforms drop the table when you create the index.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX [IX_myTable_bookid] ON [myTable] (bookid ASC)`

Comment: @Kamil G - No external tool, just ssms.

Answer (score 31):

You can execute create index script as below, which is similar to what Igor mentioned

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable (bookid)
```